# Django CSS Configuration doesn't show expected styling

Tags: python, css, django, static-linking

I'm new to Django, and I'm trying to use static files to color my website.
this is my directory hierarchy-

[image]

This is the HTML I'm trying to style, by using this code-
[image]

This is the CSS code I'm using-

[image]

This my settings.py-

[image]

No matter what I do, or if I refresh or restart the server completely- nothing happens.
I've watched so many articles and videos related to this, but I still can't figure out what am I doing wrong...

Would appreciate any help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you try to access the static files is correct. But you need to adjust your settings.py:

```
# djangotemplates/djangotemplates/settings.py

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/
import os

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Add these new lines
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a `STATICFILES_DIRS` in my `settings.py` and it works

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'to_excel/static'
]
```